# Why does Xcode 4.1 say my iPad only app can run in the iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have an iPad-only app (targeted device family is iPad, architecture is armv7), but Xcode offers both iPhone & iPad simulators to deploy to in the scheme/device dropdown. If I create a new iPad-only project from scratch, only iPad Simulator is available as a deployment target.

Why does my iPad-only project show iPhone Simulator as a device option?

Comment: It would be useful to know which version of Xcode and iOS SDK you are using.

Comment: Updated title to include xcode version 4.1

Comment: Seeing the same in Xcode 4.2.1. I'm working on two iPad apps at the moment; one gives me iPad simulator options only, the other can be run in both the iPad and iPhone simulators. I can't spot any significant differences between the (admittedly quite different) projects.

Comment: What happens when you **run** the app in the iPhone simulator? Also, what happens when you plug a real iPhone into the computer? Does that appear as an option too? Can you run on it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just resolved this in our app; it was due to a sub-project being set to target iPhone.  If you have any sub-projects, do check their target settings as well; because apparently it can affect your top-level scheme selections.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have a **tests target** too, make sure in its *build settings* that the *Targeted Device Family* is set to **iPad** as in your app's target. This might sound silly, but I have seen it before.

Then, as stated in the other answers, check the same option for any **sub-project's target** you may have included in your app's project.

Comment: Changing the Targeted Device Family (Xcode 8.3.2) for all targets to iPad fixed it for me. Note that there is no iPad option. Instead, you just have numbers. Number 2 is for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Do a quick search of your target's build settings for "Universal" and change this to iPad if necessary. That's the ONLY reason why this would be happening. The only other thing I can suggest is restarting your computer. Sometimes Xcode has even given me Mac build options for iOS apps! If none of that works, well, if it ain't broke don't fix it, as in if you can build and test it in the iPad Simulator, what's the problem??

Comment: That's not the only reason it could happen. iPad apps should be optimized for armv7 which _is_ the universal macro (ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS). And as I said, I already target iPad only for the targeted device family. In any case, new iPad only projects specify armv7 as well without any issues. I'm fine just ignoring the iPhone deployment option, but the problem is, I suspect something else is going on in the project that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

This might be occurring if you have initially started a universal app, and changed it at a later time without readjusting the settings. Just change the settings (click on the main project folder and update the settings) and there should be no problem. You can also simply create a new iPad app and copy all your files there. You can select the iPad device family to deploy your app on, and it should remember that setting every time you run it, so don't bother changing it or figuring out why it allows you to deploy on both devices; as long as it's working, keep on programming and testing.

Comment: What settings are you suggesting I change? Creating a new project is not even remotely a possibility -- we are talking 500 or so source code files, a dozen or so external projects, and hundreds of resources and configuration files that would need to be reintegrated into the project.

Comment: I started out with Universal app and by just changing "Targeted Device Family" to iPad, it then only worked for iPad. No problems.

Comment: if you read your question, it says I, not we. I thought you just started and have only a few files. I mentioned changing the settings as well for both Xcode and Simulator. If you click the project folder (blue icon with an 'A' on it and your project name written right next to it), then select the target that you have. click on Devices under iOS Application Target and change it to iPad. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. As I indicated in my question, the targeted device family is _already_ iPad.